# Separate number following underscore off end of string? Regex?

Tags: php, regex

I'm an ob-c programmer who needs some php for his current project. I'm guessing I need to use Regex for my current problem, but I have never used Regex and it has proven a lot to bite off in one go, for a single problem. Similar questions I have found on SO haven't helped me solve my problem as generally they are written for people with a fair idea of how to do something like this, and as I said, I am a total newbie in this area.

My problem is this:

I have a string, that ends with an underscore followed by a number:

$string = XXXXXXXX_123

I want to separate this into two strings:

$root = XXXXXXXX_
and
$number = 123

Things are slightly more complicated in that:

- the XXXXXX could contain other underscores or digits (e.g.. the full thing could be XX_X12_9_123, in which case I would want to separate it into XX_X12_9_ and 123. (The underscore that I want to divided after will always be the last underscore.)
- the number at the end could be any number of digits long (although it will be a minimum of 1)

(In case you haven't guessed, these are file names that need to be incremented)

thanks for your time

Comment: hint: get the position of last underscore...

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a place to have others code for you.  You need to show a substantial attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info; this problem can also be trivially solved without regexen and simple string functions.

Comment: Have you looked into http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php?

Comment: Have you tried using `explode()`?

Comment: -nevermind, thanks, although I did put that in the original question that that was the way to approach it. -Anonymous thanks for your time, my substantial effort has been a few hours of going through Stack Overflow answers and the various manuals, but like I said, it is a lot to get your head around in one go. -deceze yes, I would have like to have done it without, but every suggestion I found suggested regex @faino thanks! I didn't know about that one. -hjpotter explode won't work as there may be more than one underscore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pos = strrpos($string, '_') + 1;
$root = substr($string, 0, $pos);
$number = substr($string, $pos);
```

Comment: cheers, thanks for the helpful response.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is a way to handle it dirty, and have it wrapped in a nice function that can be reused time and time again:

```
<?php
    // Hard code it 
    $str1 = "XXXXXXXX_123";
    $last1 = strrpos($str1, "_");
    $root1 = substr($str1, 0, $last1 + 1);
    $number1 = substr($str1, $last1 + 1);
    echo("<p>Root 1: " . $root1 . "<br />Number 1: " . $number1 . "</p>");
    // Or make it a re-usable function
    // Returns Array
    function last_chr($str, $chr = "_") {
        $last = strrpos($str, $chr) + 1;
        $root = substr($str, 0, $last);
        $number = substr($str, $last);
        return(array("root" => $root, "number" => $number));
    }
    // Define second string, call function, and reference the array elements within the echo
    $str2 = "XX_X12_9_123";
    $second = last_chr($str2);
    echo("<p>Root 2: " . $second["root"] . "<br />Number 2: " . $second["number"] . "</p>");
?>
```

I suggest use of the function and using the array key referenced that it returns.

[strrpos() documentation](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

[substr() documentation](https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: thanks, I appreciate the helpful response. I'm sure I would have saved a lot of time if I hadn't been led down the regex path, as this is the type of way I would have approached it in any language I was more familiar with! But all the other answers to other peoples questions on SO I saw were suggesting the daunting regex,so I wasted a lot of time looking into that. I have already accepted the other answer, but I have up voted this too. cheers.

Comment: PHP has a bunch of native functions that save so much time and energy on the end of the programmer. I'm glad I was able to share some knowledge with you.

Answer (score 1):

for the regex solution use this pattern `(.*_)([^_]+)$`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uO7nU1)

Comment: thanks! I was hoping to learn something at the same time. Your demo is very useful in that regard. Cheers :)